# Handling trailing patterns after something like `.*` when building regex engine

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I tried to implement a regex engine using the parser combinators in Haskell.

The idea is that first parse the pattern to build a regex parser, then use the parser to parse the input text.

But my code cannot handle this scenario: if the pattern is something like `a?(a|b).*h+`, then the `h+` after `.*` will never be satisfied since the `.*` part will consume all the inputs.

(Usually the `<|>` is implemented with a `try` func, due to efficiency. But here I don't think this is the case.

Below is my code

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Matcher where

import           Data.Function (on)
import           Data.Functor (($>))
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Applicative

newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

parse :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
parse parser inp = case runParser parser inp of
  Just (a, []) -> Just a
  _ -> Nothing

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap t (Parser g) = Parser $ \inp -> fmap (\(a, inp') -> (t a, inp')) (g inp)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = Parser $ \inp -> Just (a, inp)

  (Parser f) <*> (Parser g) = Parser
    $ \inp -> case f inp of
      Nothing        -> Nothing
      Just (t, inp') -> case g inp' of
        Nothing         -> Nothing
        Just (a, inp'') -> Just (t a, inp'')

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ const Nothing

  (Parser f) <|> (Parser g) = Parser
    $ \inp -> case f inp of
      Nothing -> g inp
      Just r  -> Just r

  some p = (:) <$> p <*> (some p <|> pure [])

instance Monad Parser where
  (Parser f) >>= g = Parser
    $ \inp -> case f inp of
      Nothing        -> Nothing
      Just (a, inp') -> runParser (g a) inp'

satisfy p = Parser
  $ \case
    (x:xs)
      | p x -> Just (x, xs)
    _      -> Nothing

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (== c)

string :: String -> Parser String
string "" = pure ""
string (c:cs) = do
  char c
  string cs
  return (c:cs)

between :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser c -> Parser b
between left content right = left *> content <* right

unit :: Parser (Parser String)
unit = (do
          c <- satisfy (`notElem` ['.', '*', '?', '+', '(', ')', '|'])
          return $ fmap (:[]) (char c))
  <|> (char '.' $> fmap (:[]) (satisfy (const True)))
  <|> oneOf

oneOf :: Parser (Parser String)
oneOf = between (char '(') content (char ')')
  where
    content = do
      p1 <- unit
      rest <- many $ char '|' *> unit
      return $ foldr (<|>) p1 rest

oneOrMore :: Parser (Parser String)
oneOrMore = do
  arp <- unit
  char '+'
  return $ fmap concat (some arp)

zeroOrMore :: Parser (Parser String)
zeroOrMore = do
  arp <- unit
  char '*'
  return $ fmap concat (many arp)

zeroOrOne :: Parser (Parser String)
zeroOrOne = do
  arp <- unit
  char '?'
  return $ arp <|> pure ""

reg :: Parser (Parser String)
reg = fmap
  (foldr (liftA2 (++)) (pure ""))
  (some $ zeroOrMore <|> zeroOrOne <|> oneOrMore <|> unit)

createRegParser :: String -> Maybe (Parser String)
createRegParser = parse reg

example = createRegParser "a?(a|b).*h+"
```

Comment: The standard technique is to build an epsilon-NFA, compile that to a DFA, then execute the DFA. Can you say why this technique will not work for you?

Comment: @DanielWagner I haven't tried the automata approach yet. I'm reviewing my parser combinator knowledge so I'm wondering how to do this. And the parser combinator approach(LL parsing) is stronger than dfa, so I think there must be a way to implement it.

Comment: Alternation and repetition in regular expressions work differently than in PEGs, so you can't just take a regular expression and treat it as a PEG. You're right that PEGs are more powerful than regular expressions, but that only means that you can transform a regex into an equivalent PEG - it doesn't mean that the resulting PEG is going to look similar to the regex. In your example the PEG `S <- 'a'? ('a' / 'b') .* 'h'+` is not equivalent to the regex `a?(a|b).*h+` because PEGs don't backtrack that way. An equivalent PEG would be `S <- ('aa' / 'ab' / 'a' / 'b') H` and `H <- 'h'+ / . H`.